# Flaskapp Routing on AWS EC2 Instance Resulting in 404 Error

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2

So I was following [this tutorial here](https://medium.com/techfront/step-by-step-visual-guide-on-deploying-a-flask-application-on-aws-ec2-8e3e8b82c4f7) on deploying a flask app on an EC2 server, and I have made it all the way to the end and have the home page of this flask app correctly displaying:
[image]

however when I click submit and the flask app routs the request to the correct heading but results in a 404 error:
[image]

My flaskapp code is:

```
import transformers

import numpy as np

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
from tokenizers import BertWordPieceTokenizer
from model import model_predict, load_model, StringCleaner, Stemmer

app = Flask(__name__)
model = load_model('../Models/model.tflite', 'tflite')

tokenizer = transformers.DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-multilingual-cased')
# Save the loaded tokenizer locally
tokenizer.save_pretrained('.')
# Reload it with the huggingface tokenizers library
fast_tokenizer = BertWordPieceTokenizer('vocab.txt', lowercase=False)
#fast_tokenizer = None

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():

    text_input = list(request.form.values())
    pred_class, probability = model_predict(text_input, model, 
                                            model_type='tflite', tokenizer=fast_tokenizer)

    if pred_class.shape == (1,1):
        if pred_class[0][0] == 0:
            prediction = "Fake News"
            probability = 1 - probability
        elif pred_class[0][0] == 1:
            prediction = "True News"
    elif pred_class.shape == (1,):
        if pred_class[0] == 0:
            prediction = "Fake News"
            probability = 1 - probability
        elif pred_class[0] == 1:
            prediction = "True News"

    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Predicted {} with probability {}'.format(prediction, probability[0][0]))

@app.route('/results',methods=['POST'])
def results():

    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    text_input = list(data.values())
    pred_class, _ = model_predict(text_input, model, 
                                  model_type='tflite', tokenizer=fast_tokenizer)

    if pred_class.shape == (1,1):
        if pred_class[0][0] == 0:
            prediction = "Fake News"
            probability = 1 - probability
        elif pred_class[0][0] == 1:
            prediction = "True News"
    elif pred_class.shape == (1,):
        if pred_class[0] == 0:
            prediction = "Fake News"
            probability = 1 - probability
        elif pred_class[0] == 1:
            prediction = "True News"

    output = prediction
    return jsonify(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

And my script at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` is:

```
    ## 
    
    # You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
    
    # of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
    
    # https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
    
    # https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
    
    # https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
    
    # 
    
    # In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
    
    # leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
    
    # updated by the nginx packaging team.
    
    # 
    
    # This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
    
    # applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
    
    # available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
    
    # 
    
    # Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
    
    ## 
    
    # Default server configuration
    
    # 
    
    upstream fakenewsdetection {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen \[::\]:80 default_server;
    
        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    
        root /var/www/html;
    
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
        server_name _;
    
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                proxy_pass http://fakenewsdetection/;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    
        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}
    
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
    
    }
    
    # Virtual Host configuration for example.com
    
    # 
    
    # You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
    
    # to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
    
    # 
    
    \#server {
    
    # listen 80;
    
    # listen \[::\]:80;
    
    # 
    
    # server_name example.com;
    
    # 
    
    # root /var/www/example.com;
    
    # index index.html;
    
    # 
    
    # location / {
    
    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    
    # }
    
    \#}
```

I submitted text through the box and resulted in a 404 error, when I try `curl localhost:8000/predict` it gives me back:

````
\<!doctype html\>

405 Method Not Allowed

<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>```
````

Comment: Try `curl -X POST localhost:8000/predict`.